# Meaning of "idea" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "idea" in the following text mean?

> Smith concluded the letter by declaring that his unbelieving friend
>   approached ‘as nearly to the **idea** of a perfectly wise and virtuous
>   man, as perhaps the nature of human frailty will permit’.

None of the meaning that I could find for "idea" (concept, notion, point, thought, belief, estimate, ...) means anything in the above text. And how could someone approach an "idea"?

Comment: _Concept_ and _notion_ both have plenty of meaning in this context, even if you don't agree.

Comment: 'Idea' means to me something transitory, a light bulb moment. But a concept is a permanence.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, idea is being used to mean a [concept](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idea) (Look at definition 1-b), specifically

> an idealized concept of 'a perfectly wise and virtuous man'

If you're having trouble parsing that, it refers to the mental image a person would conjure if they were told to think of a wise and virtuous man. The passage is implying that the 'unbelieving friend' comes close to this conjured ideal.